# How do I disable the second fan?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

I've tracked Commissioner Gordon to the mall. I've opened the door and taken out the first round of goons with the Batmobile's, disabled the first ventilation fan, taken out the second set of goons across the ventilation shaft.

Now I find myself riding the elevator up and down looking for a way to the second power source under the second fan. I've tried shooting the fan's power source with the REC gun through the fan with no success. I've tried using the explosive gel to destroy the weak wall at the bottom of the elevator, but Batman just shakes his head at me in disgust.

**Where do I go from here to disable the second fan?**

Comment: It would probably help people who search for answers if you mention the quest or location you are referring to. But I haven't played Batman, to be honest, maybe there's just one Pair of Fans in the whole game :-)

Comment: @OrcJMR Added some more context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are spinning generators behind the walls that you have to overload with an electrical charge to turn off the fans.  To access the generators, you have to lower yourself in the Batmobile into the shaft as far as you can go.  There should be a shootable wall nearby that you have to shoot and go through.  Exploring the opened area should eventually lead to a generator that you have to overload with an electrical charge.  It may seem like a dead end but look around, there are shafts and whatnot that you need to go up or down to get to the generators.

Here's a playthrough that's going through that section. (it begins at around 5 minutes into the video)

[youtube](https://youtu.be/2XF4sTvLQyg?t=297)

Comment: I'm stuck before this. I've disabled the first fan and am stuck at the bottom of the elevator shaft.

Comment: The talk of three paths makes it sound more like the riddler challenge where you lower the batmobile, not the one where you are chasing after comissioner gordon. From memory you do lower down the batmobile but there is only one place you can lower it...

Comment: Though I notice that the question has been clarified since this answer.

Comment: @splatteredbits: If you're off the wall an on the drill head, you need to spin the drill down to dig all the way down as far as you can go. There's a shootable wall somewhere along the way not at the lowest level.  You'll have to raise the drill up to that level to continue further with the Batmobile.  To move the drill, you have to latch onto the handles on the side and pull so the wheels will spin the drill in the appropriate direction.

Comment: @JeffMercado I can't get to the drill. Fan blade #2 is still spinning.

Comment: @splatteredbits: Ahh, I was mixing up different locations in my head as I wrote this. I'll have to revise my answer.  As you lower the Batmobile down the shaft, there should be an opening that you have to shoot your way through on the opposite side of the shaft.  Going through those areas will eventually lead to a generator that you have to overload.  Disabling those will turn off the fans.

Comment: @Chris: Yeah, it turns out I was mixing up the two different areas. I feel like it's been ages since I've played through these areas.

Comment: OMG. The explosive gel *does* work at the bottom of the elevator shaft. Looks like Batman has to be standing in a very specific spot otherwise he gets confused. Grrrr.

Comment: @splatteredbits: Yeah, I noticed he can get finicky when it comes to setting the gel. If you are off even by a bit, he'll just be stupid and set the gel on the floor.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be standing in the room on the second floor but not inside of the elevator and use to electric charge gun to make the elevator go all the way up. Then it will be out of your way and you can jump to the bottom of the shaft and you’ll see the next room to make your way through that’s full of guards.